# Unity : Uniform thickness with linerenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, line

I make a class which draws 3 differents lines using LineRenderer. I want the lines to be stacked and correctly aligned and each line with a specific constant thickness. Each line has the same vertices so I don't know why they don't have the same shape. Can you help me please ?

Thanks for answers !

This is my code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
   private Dictionary<string, LineRenderer> renderers;
   private List<Vector2> vertices;
   private Vector2 start, end;
   private int pathSize;
   private float segmentLength;

   public int levelID;

   public void Setup(int difficulty)
   {
      levelID = difficulty;

      SetpathSize(levelID);

      ComputeSegmentLenght();

      InitRenderer();

      AddVertices();

      Draw();
   }

   public void InitRenderer()
   {
      renderers = new Dictionary<string, LineRenderer>();

      string[] areaNames = { "Safe", "Middle", "Danger" };

      foreach (string area in areaNames)
      {
         renderers.Add(area, GameObject.Find(area + "AreaDrawer").GetComponent<LineRenderer>());

         float areaWidth;
         Color areaColor;
         int drawPriority;

         switch (area)
         {
            case "Danger":
               areaColor = Color.red;
               areaWidth = 4.0f;
               drawPriority = 1;
               break;
            case "Middle":
               areaColor = Color.yellow;
               areaWidth = 1.5f;
               drawPriority = 2;
               break;
            default:
               areaColor = Color.white;
               areaWidth = 0.5f;
               drawPriority = 3;
               break;
         }

         renderers[area].widthCurve = AnimationCurve.Constant(0f, 0.5f, 1f);
         renderers[area].widthMultiplier = areaWidth;

         renderers[area].startColor = areaColor;
         renderers[area].endColor = areaColor;

         renderers[area].sortingOrder = drawPriority;
      }
   }

   public void Draw()
   {
      foreach (string area in renderers.Keys)
      {
         renderers[area].positionCount = vertices.Count;

         for (int index = 0; index < vertices.Count; index++)
         {
            renderers[area].SetPosition(index, vertices[index]);
            GameObject.Find(area + "AreaDrawer").GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>().points = vertices.ToArray();
         }
      }
   }

   private int RandYPos(bool isLimit)
   {
      int retValue;

      if (isLimit)
      {
         retValue = Random.Range(-4, 4);
      }
      else
      {
         retValue = Random.Range(-7, 7);
      }
      return retValue;
   }

   // Set the lenght between 2 vertices
   private void ComputeSegmentLenght()
   {
      // If start vertex is not initialized
      if (start == null || start.x == 0 || start.y == 0)
      {
         start = new Vector2(-7, RandYPos(true)); // Then Initialze it
      }

      // If end vertex is not initialized
      if (end == null || end.x == 0 || end.y == 0)
      {
         end = new Vector2(7, RandYPos(true)); // Then Initialze it
      }

      // Compute the length
      float distance = Vector2.Distance(start, end);
      float segmentCount = Mathf.Max(pathSize, 2);
      segmentLength = distance / segmentCount;
   }

   private void AddVertices()
   {
      if (vertices == null)
      {
         vertices = new List<Vector2>();
      }

      vertices.Add(start);

      GameObject.Find("StartPoint").GetComponent<LevelLimit>().SetPosition(start);

      float segmentCount = Mathf.Max(pathSize, 2);
      float waveFrequency = Random.Range(1f, 3f);
      float waveAmplitude = Random.Range(0.5f, 1.5f);

      Vector2 lastVertex = start;
      Vector2 lastControlPoint = Vector2.zero;
      Vector2 lastTangent = Vector2.zero;

      for (int index = 1; index < segmentCount; index++)
      {
         Vector2 newVertex = new Vector2();

         newVertex.x = start.x + index * segmentLength;
         newVertex.y = waveAmplitude * Mathf.Sin(waveFrequency * newVertex.x) + RandYPos(false);

         if (index > 1)
         {
            Vector2 newTangent = (newVertex - lastVertex).normalized;

            // Check if the current segment direction is valid for the next segment
            if (IsValidDirection(lastTangent, newTangent))
            {
               Vector2 newControlPoint = lastControlPoint + lastTangent * segmentLength / 2f;

               // Check for intersection with previous segment
               bool intersects = false;
               for (int i = vertices.Count - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
               {
                  Vector2 p1 = vertices[i];
                  Vector2 c1 = vertices[i + 1];
                  Vector2 p2 = lastVertex;
                  Vector2 c2 = lastControlPoint;

                  if (Intersects(p1, c1, p2, c2))
                  {
                     intersects = true;
                     break;
                  }
               }

               if (!intersects)
               {
                  Vector2 direction = newControlPoint - lastControlPoint;
                  Vector2 perpendicular = new Vector2(-direction.y, direction.x).normalized;
                  float controlMagnitude = Vector2.Distance(lastControlPoint, newControlPoint);
                  Vector2 offset = perpendicular * controlMagnitude * Random.Range(-1f, 1f);

                  Vector2 controlPointA = lastControlPoint + offset;
                  Vector2 controlPointB = newControlPoint + offset;

                  vertices.Add(controlPointA);
                  vertices.Add(controlPointB);

                  lastControlPoint = newControlPoint;
               }
            }
         }

         vertices.Add(newVertex);
         lastVertex = newVertex;
         lastTangent = (newVertex - lastVertex).normalized;
      }

      vertices.Add(end);

      GameObject.Find("EndPoint").GetComponent<LevelLimit>().SetPosition(end);
   }

   private bool IsValidDirection(Vector2 currentDirection, Vector2 nextDirection)
   {
      Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2[]> validDirections = new Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2[]>()
    {
        { Vector2.up, new Vector2[] { Vector2.up + Vector2.left, Vector2.up + Vector2.right, Vector2.left, Vector2.right } },
        { Vector2.up + Vector2.right, new Vector2[] { Vector2.right, Vector2.up, Vector2.up + Vector2.left } },
        { Vector2.right, new Vector2[] { Vector2.right + Vector2.up, Vector2.right + Vector2.down, Vector2.up, Vector2.down } },
        { Vector2.down + Vector2.right, new Vector2[] { Vector2.right, Vector2.down, Vector2.down + Vector2.left } },
        { Vector2.down, new Vector2[] { Vector2.down + Vector2.left, Vector2.down + Vector2.right, Vector2.left, Vector2.right } },
        { Vector2.down + Vector2.left, new Vector2[] { Vector2.left, Vector2.down, Vector2.down + Vector2.right } },
        { Vector2.left, new Vector2[] { Vector2.left + Vector2.up, Vector2.left + Vector2.down, Vector2.up, Vector2.down } },
        { Vector2.up + Vector2.left, new Vector2[] { Vector2.left, Vector2.up, Vector2.up + Vector2.right } }
    };

      // Check if the next direction is within the valid direction range for the current direction
      if (validDirections.ContainsKey(currentDirection))
      {
         Vector2[] validRange = validDirections[currentDirection];
         foreach (Vector2 validDirection in validRange)
         {
            if (Vector2.Distance(nextDirection, validDirection) < 0.001f) // Tolerance of 0.001f
            {
               return true;
            }
         }
      }
      return false;
   }

   private bool Intersects(Vector2 a1, Vector2 a2, Vector2 b1, Vector2 b2)
   {
      float den = (b2.y - b1.y) * (a2.x - a1.x) - (b2.x - b1.x) * (a2.y - a1.y);
      if (den == 0)
      {
         return false;
      }

      float ua = ((b2.x - b1.x) * (a1.y - b1.y) - (b2.y - b1.y) * (a1.x - b1.x)) / den;
      float ub = ((a2.x - a1.x) * (a1.y - b1.y) - (a2.y - a1.y) * (a1.x - b1.x)) / den;

      if (ua >= 0f && ua <= 1f && ub >= 0f && ub <= 1f)
      {
         return true;
      }

      return false;
   }

   // Set the number of vertices in the line
   private void SetpathSize(int pathSize)
   {
      this.pathSize = pathSize;

   }
}
```

This is the result with the pathSize property equal to 14 :
[image]

Comment: You should have seen the tracks in stadiums. The outer circle is longer than the inner circle in order to ensure that the thickness of each track is the same. But line segments in a LineRenderer are same long. If your line segment doesn't rotate very much, you can have better look, otherwise try to add more vertex to the corners.